# Search Sub Folders in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have written a script to search for .avi or .mkv files within a certain directory. Once found I launch a program that processes them and renames them. I am looking to find out how to modify the below script to also search sub folders.

For example. If I have test.avi or test.avi within Downloads the below works fine but if I have test.avi or test.mkv within Downloads/Test it does not work.

```
cd C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads
for %%X in (*.avi) do start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rename\Rename.exe" %%X
for %%Y in (*.mkv) do start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rename\Rename.exe" %%Y
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you look at the FOR help (type `HELP FOR` or `FOR /?` from the command prompt). The answer will be staring at you in the face. Or a simple google search should yield lots of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/r` is a recursive switch.  `""` is needed in the start command when other quoted strings exist.  `/w` pauses until the completion of each command.  The `"%%X"` quotes allows for spaces etc in the names and paths.

```
cd C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads
for /r %%X in (*.avi) do start "" /w "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rename\Rename.exe" "%%X"
for /r %%Y in (*.mkv) do start "" /w "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rename\Rename.exe" "%%Y"
```